# Pasarela de pago MercadoPago

Tags: php, mercadopago

Tengo el siguiente error a la hora de realizar un pago en modo producción con MercadoPago

```
<Error>
 <Code>AccessDenied</Code> 
<Message>Access Denied</Message> 
<RequestId>TYW4JWPZC9Q3BS10</RequestId> 
<HostId>O904fEL6/hmzqxFY8KmVgWi02uRHoRKv/gvSpe1yYfjPo+SwzMBCbqmaIhjI+I/zVWxKM7k5Jxc=</HostId> 
</Error>
```

---

Asi tengo el archivo index.php que tengo dentro de la carpeta mercadopago y me da el siguiente error que colocare en una imagen [image: ese es el error que puedo ver]

el Problema es que en modo produccion no me procesan los pagos

```
    <?php
    
    require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    
    
    /*=============================================
    Dominio 251
    =============================================*/
       
    $domain = "localhost";
    /*=============================================
    Credenciales 251
    =============================================*/
    
    $sandbox = true;
    
    if($sandbox){
    
       $public_key = "asdofgahsdofgiahsdofgiahsdogasdgas";
       $access_token = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfas";
    
    }else{
    
        $public_key = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf";
       $access_token = "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdfad";
    
    }
    
    
       /*=============================================================================
         Peticion a la API de cambio de moneda https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/
       =============================================================================*/
       $curl = curl_init();
    
         curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "http://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_CLP&compact=ultra&apiKey=24336800d0bfee0949c4",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
              "Cookie: __cfduid=d33a8b671902df6f1dfc8eb1d98756da61592509616"
           ),
         ));
    
         $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
         curl_close($curl);
         //echo $response;
         
         $jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);
    
         /*=============================
         Formulario MercadoPago 250
       ===============================*/
    
    if(isset($_GET["_x"]) && $_GET["_x"] == md5(base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]))){
    
       
          echo '
          <div style="width:100%; height:100vh; position:fixed; background:url(mp-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover">
    
          <div style="text-align:center; position:absolute; top:45vh; right:120px">
    
          <form action="http://localhost/marketplace-account/pruebas/src/mercadopago/index.php" method="POST">
         <script
           src="https://www.mercadopago.cl/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
           data-public-key="'.$public_key.'"
           data-button-label="pagar"
           data-summary-product-label="'.$_COOKIE["_p"].'"
           data-transaction-amount="'.base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]).'">
          </script>
         </form>
    
         </div>
    
        </div> ';
    
          }
    
          /*=============================================
          Recibir la respuesta de Mercado Pago 251
          =============================================*/
    
    
          if(isset($_REQUEST["token"])){
    
    
       /*=============================================
       Obtener los datos del comprador 251
       =============================================*/
    
       $token = $_REQUEST["token"];
       $payment_method_id = $_REQUEST["payment_method_id"];
       $installments = $_REQUEST["installments"];
       $issuer_id = $_REQUEST["issuer_id"];
    
         /*=============================================
          Realizar el pago con el SDK de Mercado Pago 251
          =============================================*/
    
          MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($access_token);
        //...
        $payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();
        $payment->transaction_amount = base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]);
        $payment->token = $token;
        $payment->description = $_COOKIE["_p"];
        $payment->installments = $installments;
        $payment->payment_method_id = $payment_method_id;
        $payment->issuer_id = $issuer_id;
        $payment->payer = array(
        "email" => $_COOKIE["_e"]
        );
        // Guarda y postea el pago
        $payment->save();
    
        echo $payment->status;
    
        // Imprime el estado del pago
        if($payment->status == "approved"){
    
          setcookie('_i', $payment->id, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
          setcookie('_k', $public_key, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
          setcookie('_a', $access_token, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
        echo '<script>
    
             window.location.href = ‘http://localhost:4200/shopping-cart’;
    
          </script>';
    
        }
    
    }
```

Debido al error que estoy presentando también intente **migrar desde Web Tokenize Checkout V1**

[introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://www.mercadopago.cl/developers/es/docs/checkout-bricks/how-tos/how-to-migrate/web-tokenize-checkout-v1/clientside)

Colocando el código así

```
    <?php

require __DIR__  . '/vendor/autoload.php';


/*=============================================
Dominio 251
=============================================*/
   
$domain = "localhost";
/*=============================================
Credenciales 251
=============================================*/

$sandbox = true;

if($sandbox){

   $public_key = "dghdfghdfghdfhd";
   $access_token = "dfghdfghdfhdg";

}else{

    $public_key = "dfhdfhdfh";
   $access_token = "dfghdfhdhdf";

}


   /*=============================================================================
     Peticion a la API de cambio de moneda https://free.currencyconverterapi.com/
   =============================================================================*/
   $curl = curl_init();

     curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=USD_CLP&compact=ultra&apiKey=24336800d0bfee0949c4",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
          "Cookie: __cfduid=d33a8b671902df6f1dfc8eb1d98756da61592509616"
       ),
     ));

     $response = curl_exec($curl);

     curl_close($curl);
     //echo $response;
     
     $jsonResponse = json_decode($response, true);

     /*=============================
     Formulario MercadoPago 250
   ===============================*/

if(isset($_GET["_x"]) && $_GET["_x"] == md5(base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]))){

   
      echo '
      <div style="width:100%; height:100vh; position:fixed; background:url(mp-bg.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:cover">

      <div style="text-align:center; position:absolute; top:45vh; right:120px">

  


     <script src="https://sdk.mercadopago.com/js/v2"></script>
      <div id="cardPaymentBrick_container"></div>

      <script>
         const mp = new MercadoPago("'.$public_key.'");
const bricksBuilder = mp.bricks();
const renderPaymentBrick = async (bricksBuilder) => {
   const settings = {
       initialization: {
           amount: "'.base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]).'", //valor do processamento a ser realizado
           payer: {
           email: "'.$_COOKIE["_e"].'",
       },
       },
       style: {
           theme: 'default' // | 'dark' | 'bootstrap' | 'flat'
       },
       callbacks: {
           onReady: () => {
           // callback chamado quando o Brick estiver pronto
           },
           onSubmit: ({paymentType, formData}) => {
           // callback chamado o usuário clicar no botão de submissão dos dados
           // ejemplo de envío de los datos recolectados por el Brick a su servidor
           return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
               fetch("/processar-pago", {
                   method: "POST",
                   headers: {
                       "Content-Type": "application/json",
                   },
                   body: JSON.stringify(formData)
               })
               .then((response) => {
                   // receber o resultado do pagamento
                   resolve();
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                   // lidar com a resposta de erro ao tentar criar o pagamento
                   reject();
               })
               });
           },
           onError: (error) => {
           // callback chamado para todos os casos de erro do Brick
           },
       },
   };
   window.cardPaymentBrickController = await bricksBuilder.create('payment', 'paymentBrick_container', settings);
};
renderPaymentBrick(bricksBuilder);

      </script>

     </div>

    </div> ';

      }

      /*=============================================
      Recibir la respuesta de Mercado Pago 251
      =============================================*/


      if(isset($_REQUEST["token"])){


   /*=============================================
   Obtener los datos del comprador 251
   =============================================*/

   $token = $_REQUEST["token"];
   $payment_method_id = $_REQUEST["payment_method_id"];
   $installments = $_REQUEST["installments"];
   $issuer_id = $_REQUEST["issuer_id"];

     /*=============================================
      Realizar el pago con el SDK de Mercado Pago 251
      =============================================*/

      MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken($access_token);
    //...
    $payment = new MercadoPago\Payment();
    $payment->transaction_amount = base64_decode($_COOKIE["_x"]);
    $payment->token = $token;
    $payment->description = $_COOKIE["_p"];
    $payment->installments = $installments;
    $payment->payment_method_id = $payment_method_id;
    $payment->issuer_id = $issuer_id;
    $payment->payer = array(
    "email" => $_COOKIE["_e"]
    );
    // Guarda y postea el pago
    $payment->save();

    echo $payment->status;

    // Imprime el estado del pago
    if($payment->status == "approved"){

      setcookie('_i', $payment->id, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
      setcookie('_k', $public_key, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
      setcookie('_a', $access_token, time() + 3600, "/", $domain);
    echo '<script>

         window.location.href = ‘http://localhost:4200/shopping-cart’;

      </script>';

    }

}
```

y tengo el siguiente error

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'default' (T_DEFAULT), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace-account\pruebas\src\mercadopago\index.php on line 86
```

Elimino la Siguiente linea

```
    style: {
           theme: 'default' // | 'dark' | 'bootstrap' | 'flat'
       },
```

Y tengo el Siguiente Error

```
    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'payment' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\marketplace-account\pruebas\src\mercadopago\index.php on line 116


 

       window.cardPaymentBrickController = await bricksBuilder.create('payment', 'paymentBrick_container', settings);
```

Comment: <Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>TYW4JWPZC9Q3BS10</RequestId>
<HostId>O904fEL6/hmzqxFY8KmVgWi02uRHoRKv/gvSpe1yYfjPo+SwzMBCbqmaIhjI+I/zVWxKM7k5Jxc=</HostId>
</Error>

Comment: Y cómo está implementada la integración? Cómo le estás enviando el pago? Revisaste si estás autenticando la petición correctamente?

Comment: Bienvenido, te sugerimos revisar [ask], agrega más información a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: No pude editar la misma pregunta para colocar el error que tengo, pero aca les dejo el  error como pregunta